# Newton's Laws of motion class 9

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum

How is force proportional to the rate of change in momentum? Isn't force proportional just to momentum?

Comment: hello  This is your first question on physics stack exchange. I would like to tell you that you should tell us why do you think that force is proportional just to momentum. Did you read it somewhere ? If yes, kindly share the link or picture.

Comment: Force is the **rate of change** of momentum -- force describes how momentum *changes over time*

Answer (score 4):

> Isn't force proportional just to momentum?

No. Linear momentum $p$ is defined as

$$p=mv$$

Assuming the mass is constant, then if the momentum is not changing the speed (magnitude of $v$) has to be constant in a straight line.

Newton's first law states: if a body is at rest or moving at constant speed in a straight line, it will remain at rest or keep moving in a straight line at constant speed *unless acted upon by a force*. This tells us that if the momentum is constant, there is no net force acting on the mass $m$.

If the velocity is changing in time, then, per Newton's second law

$$\frac{dp}{dt}=m\frac{dv}{dt}=ma=F_{net}$$

Which tells us force equals the rate of change of momentum.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

No, force is not proportional to momentum.

You can consider Newton's second law to be the definition of what a force is, and this precisely says that $\vec{F} = \frac{\text{d}\vec{p}}{\text{d}t}$, i.e. force is equal to the rate of change in momentum.

You can easily have momentum and no force, or force and no momentum. For instance, a free particle flying through empty space has momentum, but is not acted on by any force. On the other hand, you sitting on your chair are acted on by various forces (gravity, the normal force from the chair), but if you are motionless your momentum is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Momentum is due to a mass's inertia and requires no forces to maintain a constant velocity. A net force on a mass will cause acceleration of the mass thereby causing a change in its momentum proportional to the force..

Answer (score 0):

$F_{ext}$ $\propto$ $\frac{p_2 - p_1}{t_2 - t_1}$

$\frac{mv_2 - mv_1}{t_2 - t_1}$

$m[$ $\frac{v_2 - v_1}{t_2 - t_1}$ ]

$F = m * a $.

Therefore , Force is proportional to the rate of change of momentum where the proportionality constant = 1.