# Why is acceleration inversely proportional to the mass of an object, but directly proportional to force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

Why is acceleration of an object inversely proportional to its mass, but directly proportional to force?

Comment: The relationship between the motion of an object and the forces acting on it are described by Newton's laws. Isaac Newton according to a series of observations formulated his second law as
$$\vec F=m\vec a,$$
where $\vec F$ is the force acting on the object, $m$ is the mass of the object and $\vec a$ is the object's acceleration. You can write this as $\vec a=\frac{\vec F}{m}$. This means that if you apply the same force to two objects having different masses, the object with the smaller mass will gain more acceleration. Apparently $m$ measures the resistance to any change in its velocity.

Comment: If you have understood the question. Then , do accept an answer. Thank you,

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am new here and not sure how to accept. I am still working on this as I re-learning these concepts. Nonetheless, I find this very helpful!

Comment: @AnnHaney Every answer that you see. There is ✔️ option on left.

Comment: @AnnHaney If you click on tick. Your answer is accepted. Also , there is ⬆️ and down symbol present. It is where the users have written the answer. Up means upvote and down means downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know $F = m * a$ . Then , you rearrange the equation.

a = $\frac{ F }{m}$.

Case 1: Considering F to be const :

Acceleration is inversely proportional to mass.

Case 2: Considering m to be constant:

Acceleration is directly proportional to Force.

It will be a different question if you ask why is F = m *a. You can check this answer of mine if you do have.
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/638836/287551

Hence proved. Do let me know if you have any difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

A force is needed to change the speed of an object, and the change of speed is the acceleration. And mass can be thought of as a property of an object with which it resists acceleration (this is called inertia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia for further reading). The relationship between these quantities is then $\vec F= m \cdot \vec a$.

Comment: Thank you for this... Very very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

By convention we decide that mass is an an important attribute of an object (since it measures the amount of "stuff" in the object), and then the equation

$\displaystyle a = \frac F m$

establishes that acceleration is proportional to applied force but inversely proportional to mass. This makes intuitive sense - the more "stuff" there is in an object, the more difficult it is to accelerate it.

But we could instead decide that the reciprocal of mass was the important attribute (in the same way as we sometimes talk about the electrical conductance of an object rather than its resistance). Let's call the reciprocal of mass "ssam", and denote it by "w". Then we would have

$a = F w$

In other words, acceleration is now directly proportional to both applied force and "ssam".

Answer (score 1):

Force is rate of change of momentum:

$$ \vec F = \frac{d\vec p}{dt}$$

and $\vec p = m\vec v$. So:

$$ \vec F = m\frac{d\vec v}{dt} + \dot m \vec v$$

With $\dot m= 0$ and $\vec a\equiv d\vec v/dt$:

$$ \vec F=m\vec a $$